# Why am I getting correct output even though the code is logically incorrect

Tags: c

Following is the code for reducing a given number to a single digit by adding the digits of the number recursively.

For example if the input is `845` the output is `8`. `8+4+5 = 17 -> 1+7 = 8` (output)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TRUE 1

int reduceToSingle(int numb);

int main() 
{
    int numb;
    scanf("%d",&numb);
    printf("Original = %d Single digit = %d\n", numb, reduceToSingle(numb));

    return TRUE;
} 

int reduceToSingle(int numb)
{
    int sum = 0, digit = 0;
    for (digit = numb % 10; numb != 0; numb = numb / 10)
    {
        digit = numb % 10;
        sum += digit;
    }

    if (sum > 9)
        reduceToSingle(sum);
    else
        return sum;
}
```

In the above code in the `if (sum > 9)` block I haven't returned the function value. I just called the function instead. Logically this function should give an incorrect value. But when I ran the above program in my system I got the correct sum of digits in output. I am unable to comprehend the logic behind this behaviour.

Comment: If you step through the code using your debugger you will see what is happening.

Comment: There is not logic behind it. A program with undefined behavior can have *any* result, including the one you expected.

Comment: In this other question, only 1 out of 5 answers is "correct" [Incorrect output from recursive function to compute sum of digits of a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045189/incorrect-output-from-recursive-function-to-compute-sum-of-digits-of-a-number)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just undefined behavior and I'm sure you got a warning. It *happens* to work - tweak the compiler settings or change the compiler altogether and it won't anymore.

In this case I suspect `eax` isn't clobbered so you get the expected value, i.e. the last value `return`ed by any of the calls. So when you call `reduceToSingle`, it will eventually reach `return` (when `sum <= 9`). From then on the value of `eax` will trickle down to the original caller.

Comment: yes, when i compiled it with -Wall option enabled i was thrown th following warning  warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]   Also could you please tell me how to tweak the compiler inorder to get rid of such undefined behavior?

Comment: @svKris No, you can't do that. You can however not write it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i got

```
815
Original = 815 Single digit = 2009291924
```

in your code reduceToSingle(numb) is not returning any value in the code so it is something like

```
printf("%d %d",12);
```

so a garbage value is printed for the other format specifier